# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Android Studio IDE

Tags: java, android

I have tried installing and uninstalling Android Studio multiple times but every time I get this error:

> 99 >= 99 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 99 >= 99   at
>   java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)   at
>   javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.getChildAt(DefaultMutableTreeNode.java:245)
>     at com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.listChildren(TreeUtil.java:769)
>     at com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.sortChildren(TreeUtil.java:335)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.sortRecursively(TreeUtil.java:326)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.sortRecursively(TreeUtil.java:329)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.sortRecursively(TreeUtil.java:329)
>     at com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.sort(TreeUtil.java:322)   at
>   com.intellij.ide.scopeView.ClassesScopeTreeStructureExpander.treeWillExpand(ClassesScopeTreeStructureExpander.java:107)
>     at javax.swing.JTree.fireTreeWillExpand(JTree.java:2832)    at
>   javax.swing.JTree.setExpandedState(JTree.java:3573)   at
>   javax.swing.JTree.expandPath(JTree.java:2212)     at
>   com.intellij.packageDependencies.ui.TreeExpansionMonitor.restore(TreeExpansionMonitor.java:110)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.scopeView.ScopeTreeViewPanel$MyModuleRootListener$1.lambda$run$0(ScopeTreeViewPanel.java:779)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.util.ExecutionCallback.setExecuted(ExecutionCallback.java:58)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback.setDone(ActionCallback.java:72)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.scopeView.ScopeTreeViewPanel.lambda$refreshScope$1(ScopeTreeViewPanel.java:347)
>     at
>   com.intellij.packageDependencies.ui.FileTreeModelBuilder$1.onSuccess(FileTreeModelBuilder.java:176)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.finishTask(CoreProgressManager.java:457)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.lambda$run$0(ProgressManagerImpl.java:189)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)   at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

I dont actually understand whats wrong or what I can do to make the IDE work? Is there any fix to it?

Comment: Please add your relevant code as well.

Comment: This is not related to any application code. I created a template project automatically in Android Studio and this error shows up in the IDE.

Comment: remove equal ( = ) from your code because ArrayList starts from zero